# Cannot access a function in the same class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have 2 methods and want to call one method in the other method. but I get an exception

> (node:17364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: GetVouchers is not defined

```
class  VoucherRepository
{
  AddNewVoucher(newVoucher) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       //  ...
        DBModel.Voucher.create(newVoucher).then((result)=>{ // when it completed

            (async function(){
            let vouchers =await GetVouchers();
            resolve(vouchers);
          })();
        });
    });
  }    

  async GetVouchers()
  {        
    console.log('getVouchers');    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    DBModel.Voucher.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

      var voucherList=[];
     // .....      
      resolve(voucherList);

    });        
    });
  }
}    
module.exports = VoucherRepository;
```

as can bee seen, I call GetVouchers() method in AddNewVoucher method after I've created a voucher. I believe that it is some how related with Promise but I could not solve.

and I call AddNewVoucher as follow

```
var voucherRepository = new VoucherRepository();
return voucherRepository.AddNewVoucher(newVoucher);
```

PS: I can call GetVouchers alone and it works..

```
return voucherRepository.GetVouchers();
```

**Update:** I've already tried this keyword but I get the same error.

```
let vouchers =await this.GetVouchers();//router.getVouchers();
```

> (node:16364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'GetVouchers' of undefined

Comment: You have to use `this` or some other saved reference to the context object in order to access other object properties and methods; it's never implicit in JavaScript.

Comment: `this.GetVouchers()`  and `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` and `(async () => { ... })()` ...

Comment: sorry to not mentioned, I tried also with this as well but I have the same error. @Pointy

Comment: @JonasWilms I tried that already...

Comment: The `function () { ... }` breaks the reference to `this`. Read both duplicates again.